# how to change an image in an app on a daily basis over the internet

Tags: ios, web-applications

how do i code an application (Xcode) that allows me to change a picture and some text daily without the users having to download updates every day?

i have a lots of pieces of art that i would like people to see and read about but i would like it to be the type of app that they go to once a day to see the picture and read about it. this means that i have to be able to change the picture and accompanying text remotely so that the people who have downloaded the app can receive it over the internet without having to download an update from the store. additionally this isnt an app based on a website so "UIWebView" won't work.

i know that such apps can be coded as i have apps like it on my Iphone such as Groupon which lets me see a new deal everyday with out me having to download an update.

i have looked all over the internet for tutorials and blogs but have not been able  to find anything relevant.

thank you for taking the time to read my question and really hope that you have an answer. if you think a blog or youtube video can help please post it and i will read/watch it!

sincerely

Comment: >i have looked all over the internet for tutorials and blogs but have not been able to find **anything relevant**.  That's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either recommend you to design a feed/rss reader in such a way that you can update ur feed everyday which gets published in your app. difference would be you will delete old feed and display only one feed with image and some text. you might want to check out http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader/ which publishes author's blog feeds. That is the easiest possible solution. Complex solution would be to setup a webservice and use the response it provides to display data.

Comment: Thanks, im new so am trying to get all the help i can!|

couple of quick questions:

1. if i set up an Rss feed could i do a separate one for the text and one for the picture?

2. would the users be able to navigate away form my specific feed?

3. if i did decide to setup a webservice and use the response it provides to display data how would i set it up within the app?

Comment: 1. Its possible but trickier. 2. Allowing navigation is upto you,you can disable user from navigating away from specific feed. 3. Its same thing as kevin described above. Webservice provides a response in JSON/XML format. you have to parse it in your app and chache(temp storage)/display.

Comment: to start understanding i would advise you to go through http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader-with-ios6/ tutorial. It is not the same thing you are asking but it will give you idea about how to get response from server and parse it so that you can display it in your app.

Comment: np..glad i could help.

Comment: i've been looking around, is their a need for a webpage prior to setting up a RSS feed?

Comment: just to see how it works you can setup a tumblr blog. example xyz.tumblr.com.. so your RSS url will be xyz.tumblr.com/rss.. so every post you create will be seen your feed via your RSS URL..

Comment: try this. http://staff.tumblr.com/rss.. thats the XML file that your app will parse and display the feed.

Comment: Thanks, can i set it tat the people can not navigate away from my page? 2, can i make that they only see the one i intend for them to see on that specific date?

Comment: lets move this conversation to chat room -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35083/fasttrack-ios

Comment: not sure i can due to my lack of reputation points! maybe if you send me a message to start it may work if not should i email you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a very generic question. But your app needs to download the resources from a web server during runtime. Let me give you a hint.

To retrieve an image, for example, you could do the following:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/image.jpg"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError* error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    if (error == nil && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
}];
```

You could then display the image to the user. You also might want to cache the image so that you don't have to download it more than once for the same user / device.

You can do the same thing for the text, which could be encapsulated in a JSON file that you download from your web server as well.

Comment: thanks @kevin, as i'm new to coding (only been learning for 5 weeks of youtube) could you please explain a few things?

1. would i have to build a website for it?
2. what is "cache"?
3. what is a "JSON" file?